# Google Sites external link

Tags: google-sites

I am trying to add a simple link to text in google site.
For some unknown reason, it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<p><a href="www.google.com">my link</a></p>
```

When I click on it I see the error:

*The requested URL /embeds/16cb204cf3a9d4d223a0a3fd8b0eec5d/www.google.com was not found on this server. That’s all we know*

Any idea what is causing this error? I am aware I can just use google's insert link graphical interface, but I am trying to understand why is coding not working.

Comment: `https://www.google.com`. HTML basics, try to read any tutorial with HTML basics.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I know HTML, guess it has been a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is is bit incorrect, have you tried out this.

```
<p><a href="https://google.com">My url</a>
```

Comment: Ok, this is embarrassing. Just adding https in the front works. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: My pleasure :-)